# how to add image or Logo in pdf Using Html Worker for Saving Html to Pdf in Jsp

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "<html><body><div>(i) the recognised association shall have the approval of the Forward  Markets  Commission established under the Forward  Contracts (Regulation) Act, 1952 (74 of 1952) in respect of trading in derivatives and shall function in accordance with the guidelines or conditions laid down by the Forward  Markets  Commission; </div>  <body> </html>";
        try {
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Test.pdf"));
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(result));
            document.close();
            file.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This my code to to save From Html to Pdf  Using itext and Html worker I am able to convert Html File to Pdf But i Need to add On static Image{Logo} in Pdf On  Top of Pdf mean to say 
That  if first  Logo image then Text should appear please Help me i am Unable to do This..

Answer (score 0):

i thing its a good practice to use `itext` for all your pdf manipulations, i don't think `html worker` is good enough for your need. see [This](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=3481bc7bb4ae9374&q=itext%20pdf%20image%20example&safe=off) for image pdf related tutorials..